# creating stored procedure in ubuntu terminal

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create stored procedures in mysql. I am doing it on terminal (ubunutu).
But when I am adding `;` before `end` it executes all lines and throw an error .
I am trying to write

```
  create procedure test()
-> begin
-> select * from salary;
```

I am unable to add `end` in last and it executeds and got this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3.

Is this a right way to write stored procedure in terminal ?

Can I write stored procedure on separate file?

Then how can I execute that stored procedure written in file ?

Comment: Already answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/how-to-create-a-mysql-stored-procedure-through-linux-terminal

Comment: This answer in the same thread: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41381/42478

Answer (score 0):

fortunately i found a way to write a stored procedures on terminal

http://alextsilverstein.com/programming-and-development/mysql/mysql-the-reason-for-using-the-delimiter-statement-in-mysql-routines-stored-procedures-functions-triggers/